# Spring RMI TCP Connection Memory Consumption is increasing

Tags: java, spring, memory, jboss, rmi

I have a webapp developed using spring framework (with SpringToolSuite) that is deployed on a JBoss 7.1.1.Final server.
The application runs fine for some time but after some time (depends on the load) the jvm crashes. I realized that this happens if the memory consumption of the java process is very high. Interestingly the heap (inspected with visualvm, java mission control, etc.) is stable and not increasing. There is also no heap space error or something similar.
Using visualvm I saw that a Thread called "RMI TCP Connection" is consuming the biggest amount of memory and it get's more every second. This also happens if I only run the default spring application shipped with Spring Tool Suite.

So my question is what is causing this Thread to consume so much memory and why isn't if flushing/releasing memory.

The trace from the Thread Dump is as follows:

```
"RMI TCP Connection(3)-10.1.3.19" #23 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x09b08c00 nid=0x1de4  runnable [0x0988f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    - locked <0x060c3768> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:539)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:812)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:671)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x060c38e0> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

Comment: Crashes with OOME? This thread is handling RMI calls. What does the remote method *do?*

Comment: This is what I don't know. I think it is handling http messages. This example app is not crashing but my own app. The own app crashes with RUNTIME_ACCESS_VIOLATION and this happens when memory consumption is very high. e.g. Xms/Xms set to 512MB and PermGenSpace to 256MB it crashes when the memory consumption of the java process is about at 880MB. The app crashes in a third-party library provided by SAP (SAP DI API Java Connector).

Comment: Remote methods don't handle HTTP messages. They handle RMI calls.

Comment: Sounds reasonable :-) So what is causing the momory consumption of these threads? I created the sample "Spring Project" in STS and hit "run as Java Application". Nothing changed in the code.